# python pandas: find the element that is a string in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.5

Say i have a pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,'e',4], 'b': [1,2,3,4,5]})
```

I would like to have the index of where the element of df is a string. 
How can i do that other than by checking element after element
which slow and inefficient?

Comment: `df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))`? What is your expected output?

Comment: *Always* use the generic Python tag. Only use python version-specific tags if your questions is about a specific version. This one really isn't/

Comment: Also, you've given up all hope of fast and efficient operations on your `'a'` column, since it uses `dtype=object`. Note, solutions using `apply` et. al. are essentially for-loops anyway.

Comment: @Zero note, that solution is essentially equivalent to "checking element after element" in a "slow and inefficient" manner. EDIT: which, I'm sure you are aware, but mostly just trying to let the OP know.

Comment: Agree, I was pointing out, OP can avoid explicit for loop and setting values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly what you were asking. It rather returns you an index of elements that **can't** be converted to numeric values:

```
In [231]: df
Out[231]:
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  e  4
4  4  5

In [232]: df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').isnull().any(1)
Out[232]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool

In [233]: df.loc[df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').isnull().any(1)]
Out[233]:
   a  b
3  e  4
```

Or [more efficient variant from @Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46550069/python-pandas-find-the-element-that-is-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe/46550241?noredirect=1#comment80054979_46550241), which will check only `string` (`object`) columns:

```
In [237]: df.select_dtypes(['object']).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').isnull().any(1)
Out[237]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool

In [238]: df[df.select_dtypes(['object']).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').isnull().any(1)]
Out[238]:
   a  b
3  e  4
```

Comment: Note: if the intent is to capture `'3'` as well in `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,'3','e',4], 'b': [1,2,3,4,5]})`, this may not work.

Comment: `df.select_dtypes('object').apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').isnull().any(1)` will reduce the lookup on numeric column perhaps?